# Função em C que mova todos os zeros para esquerda, o restantes valores devem manter a ordem inicial (Ex.: 5,0,3,0,0,8,0,2 | result: 0,0,0,0,5,3,8,2)

Tags: c

Isto foi o que consegui fazer; Está errado, claro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 15

void zeros(int *v, int tam);

void main()
{
     int  v[TAM] = {3,4,0,2,0,5,6,0,0,7,9,1,0,0};
     
     zeros(v, TAM);
}

void zeros(int *v, int tam)
{
    int vet[TAM];
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < tam; ++i)
    {
        if(v[i] == 0){
            vet[j++] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < tam; ++i){
        if(v[i] != 0){
            vet[j++] = v[i];
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        printf("%d", vet[i]);
    }

}
```

Pretendo uma função simples tal como esta. Desde já agradeço

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Como deveria ficar o vetor após o uso da função? Quais as dificuldades e mensagens de erro?

Comment: Mantenha a ORDEM a  posição seria impossível ...

Comment: Olá! Na execução na mostra nada na consola. Esse é o problema

Comment: A ordem que estou a tentar dizer aqui são dos numeros  (\0) devem manter ordem que estão antes (Ex. 3,0,5,0,2,0,0   | result: 0,0,0,0,3,5,2)

Comment: AGRADEÇO à ideia

Answer (score 1):

Percebi que o código apenas verifica os elementos que são 0 dentro do vetor, mas não realiza o `swap` (mudar o elemento 0 para esquerda) de maneira eficiente.

### Código com os zeros para esquerda

O código abaixo que eu desenvolvi, ele faz uma verificação se o elemento do vetor é 0, e se for, é realizado um `swap` ou seja, ele troca de posição com o elemento que não é 0, e assim chegando no resultado que você deseja.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 14

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void zeros(int *v, int tamanho)
{
    int i = 0;
    int count = tamanho - 1;
    for( i = tamanho - 1; i >= 0; --i){
        if(v[i] != 0){
            swap(&v[i], &v[count--]);
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int i;

    int  v[TAM] = {3,4,0,2,0,5,6,0,0,7,9,1,0,0};

    zeros(v, TAM);

    for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf("%d - ", v[i]);
    }
}
```

### Resultado

```
0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 3 - 4 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 9 - 1 -
```

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente. Obrigado!